# AlertDialog Performance Issue

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have a case where I need multiple `checkboxes` so that can apply a filter on some results as per selected items. I have used a `Listview` having a simple `checkbox` in it and put this layout in `AlertDialog`.

```
alertDialog.setView(view); //in view I have got inflated my layout
```

There is a `button` upon clicking it I'm triggering the `AlertDialog`.

My issue is upon clicking the `button` it takes more than 3-4 seconds to show the `AlertDialog` which is a bad UI experience.

Unfortunately I'm unable to put my code, but its very simple as I have explained.

I need to ask am I doing any thing wrong? as triggering it from `onClick()` or I have to use `Handler` or `Worker Thread`.Can any one guide me or give me insight of the problem so that I can make the performance better.

Right now I have tested with 8 `checkboxes` , and in my case I can have upto 20 `checkboxes`.

Comment: Try to use DialogFragment

Comment: Even with 20 checkboxes, loading the view shouldn't be taking 3-4 seconds. Can you post the code or describe what other processing you are doing.

Comment: Did you create the AlertDialog in the onClickListener of your Button? You can pre-build the AlertDialog in Activity, then just call AlertDialog.show() in your onClickListener.

Comment: @adelphus actually due to office restriction I am unable to access SO from there and at home I don't have the code..however  as I said I simply inflated my Layout and put the view object in alertDialog and no other computation...

Comment: @Chatea yes i m creating completly inside onClick()... will try your suggestion and update